# How to Truncate Multiple Table in SSIS ( using ADO.NET Destination and Oracle Database)

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, ado.net, truncate

I got a little trouble in SSIS. I have multiple table and i want adding Truncate statement so that table can't create double data.

This is the image of package that I made :

[image: http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h140/cindylolietra/17027495-bb91-4f8c-a660-c5eebab904ba_zps64ac0ad9.png]

each Data Flow, i used Flat File Source and ADO NET Destination.

And then, in Execute SQL Task i want to apply Truncate Table

[image: http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h140/cindylolietra/truncate2_zps1b39513d.png]

After that, i have error message :

> "[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "truncate table Table1
>   truncate table Tabl..." failed with the following error: "ERROR
>   [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00911: invalid character".  Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly."

What i must suppose to do?

P.S 
Sorry if my english is not good

Comment: Have you tried by changing your result set? Seems Result set is causing the error.

Comment: "TRUNCATE TABLE <table name>" must be the statement your execute. If you want to truncate several tables you should do it in a cycle - one statement  for every table. There is no such syntax in Oracle you are trying to use.

Comment: @Oasis but the problem is not in the interest Result set, but i think in SQL Statement.

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov Yes, i've tried to make one Execute SQL Task for one table. But is there another way?

Comment: @Cindy Can you able to truncate single table.I haven't used oracle with SSIS. If you can able to truncate the single table in oracle then the problem might be your bunch of truncate statements.

Comment: @Cindy As I said above you can truncate tables one after another - one statement for every table (in cycle for example).

Comment: I've tried in SQLStatement 
truncate table Table1;
truncate table Table2;
...

but is not working. still got the same error message.

Comment: and then, i tried this>> http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h140/cindylolietra/truncate3_zpsb888122f.png

and it's work, i use one Execute SQL Task for truncate one table, but same question, is there another way? just use one Execute SQL Task?

Answer (score 2):

Since the destination is an Oracle Database you should use this syntax:

```
begin
   execute immediate 'truncate table t1';
   execute immediate 'truncate table t2';
end;
```

Comment: thank you @Marco.. that syntax is working :) Please vote my post :D

Answer (score 0):

Does this syntax work:

```
truncate table table1;

truncate table table2;
```

Note the semi colons.